# Building ffmpeg deb package gives fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2

Tags: dpkg, packaging, deb, ffmpeg

I am trying to build my first .deb package (with ffmpeg sources) and I get some errors. Those are my steps that can be reproduced to get this error:

```
git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg-git                                                                                                                                                                                        
cd ffmpeg-git
git checkout n2.4.2
cd ..
mv ffmpeg-git ffmpeg-2.4.2
tar -czf ffmpeg-2.4.2.tar.gz ffmpeg-2.4.2
cd ffmpeg-2.4.2
dh_make --copyright gpl -f ../ffmpeg-2.4.2.tar.gz
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us -B -rfakeroot

dpkg-buildpackage: source package ffmpeg
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2.4.2-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Patryk <mail@mail.com>
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 dpkg-source --before-build ffmpeg-2.4.2
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean  --with autotools-dev
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/XXXXX/programming/tools/vlc/ffmpeg-2.4.2'
Makefile:2: config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:58: /common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:99: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:99: /library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:101: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:184: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/XXXXX/programming/tools/vlc/ffmpeg-2.4.2'
dh_auto_clean: make -j1 distclean returned exit code 2
make: *** [clean] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
```

**EDIT**

Trying debuild:

```
debuild
 dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc
dpkg-buildpackage: source package ffmpeg
dpkg-buildpackage: source version 2.4.2-1
dpkg-buildpackage: source distribution unstable
dpkg-buildpackage: source changed by Patryk <mail@mail.com>
 dpkg-source --before-build ffmpeg-2.4.2
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture amd64
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
dh clean  --with autotools-dev
   dh_testdir
   dh_auto_clean
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/XXXXX/programming/tools/vlc/ffmpeg-2.4.2'
Makefile:2: config.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:58: /common.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:99: /libavutil/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:99: /library.mak: No such file or directory
Makefile:101: /doc/Makefile: No such file or directory
Makefile:184: /tests/Makefile: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `/tests/Makefile'.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/XXXXX/programming/tools/vlc/ffmpeg-2.4.2'
dh_auto_clean: make -j1 distclean returned exit code 2
make: *** [clean] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc -v failed
```

**EDIT1**

`debian/rules`

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
# -*- makefile -*-
# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
  dh $@  --with autotools-dev
```

**EDIT2**

error after adding @user26687 changes

```
INSTALL libavutil/ffversion.h
INSTALL libavutil/libavutil.pc
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/XXXXX/programming/tools/vlc/ffmpeg-2.4.2'
   dh_installdocs
        install -g 0 -o 0 -d debian/ffmpeg/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg
        cp -a README.md debian/ffmpeg/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg
        chown -R 0:0 debian/ffmpeg/usr/share/doc
        chmod -R go=rX debian/ffmpeg/usr/share/doc
        chmod -R u\+rw debian/ffmpeg/usr/share/doc
        install -g 0 -o 0 -m 644 -p debian/README.Debian debian/ffmpeg/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg/README.Debian
        install -g 0 -o 0 -m 644 -p debian/copyright debian/ffmpeg/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg/copyright
   dh_installchangelogs
        install -o 0 -g 0 -p -m644 debian/changelog debian/ffmpeg/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg/changelog.Debian
   dh_perl
   dh_usrlocal
dh_usrlocal: debian/ffmpeg/usr/local/share/man/man3/libavdevice.3 is not a directory
dh_usrlocal: debian/ffmpeg/usr/local/share/man/man3/libswscale.3 is not a directory
dh_usrlocal: debian/ffmpeg/usr/local/share/man/man3/libswresample.3 is not a directory
dh_usrlocal: debian/ffmpeg/usr/local/share/man/man3/libavcodec.3 is not a directory
dh_usrlocal: debian/ffmpeg/usr/local/share/man/man3/libavutil.3 is not a directory
dh_usrlocal: debian/ffmpeg/usr/local/share/man/man3/libavformat.3 is not a directory
dh_usrlocal: debian/ffmpeg/usr/local/share/man/man3/libavfilter.3 is not a directory
        "rmdir debian/ffmpeg/usr/local/share/man/man3"
rmdir: failed to remove ‘debian/ffmpeg/usr/local/share/man/man3’: Directory not empty
dh_usrlocal: rmdir debian/ffmpeg/usr/local/share/man/man3 returned exit code 1
make: *** [binary] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1364:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc -b failed
```

Answer (score 0):

**Could you**

Add your debian/rules file as now I'm just guessing:

**At here**

Minimal debian/rules.

With the Trusty the package building didn't work as the
dh_auto_clean was executed too early.

changelog at here:

> add override_dh_auto_clean to the debian/rules. With the Trusty the
>   make is executed before the configure step; dh_auto_clean -> make (?)

I have in the debian rules:

```
override_dh_auto_clean:
    dh_testdir
    dh_clean
```

**-----EDIT-----**

Tested with the Ubuntu 14.10.

With the debian/rules:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
# -*- makefile -*-
# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
  dh $@  --with autotools-dev
```

I get the same error as you.

With the debian/rules:

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
# -*- makefile -*-
# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
#export DH_VERBOSE=1

%:
    dh $@  --with autotools-dev

override_dh_auto_clean:

override_dh_auto_configure:
    ./configure --enable-gpl
```

The building is going on...

The 'override_dh_auto_configure:' is there as I do get an error with the dh_auto_configure:

```
Unknown option "--build=x86_64-linux-gnu".
See ./configure --help for available options.
dh_auto_configure: ./configure --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --includedir=${prefix}/include --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/ffmpeg --disable-maintainer-mode --disable-dependency-tracking returned exit code 1
debian/rules:7: recipe for target 'build' failed
```

Comment: I have added my `debian/rules` file (I didn't change anything in it).

Comment: Added info from a test with the Ubuntu 14.10

Comment: It helped but I still got an error (added in the question description).

Comment: The dh_usrlocal is whining as it is expecting a directory. Googling - few hits: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1897597 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7459644/why-is-dh-usrlocal-throwing-a-build-error. Another option is to use the /opt directory.